# When I use java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation#redefineClasses(), should I pass an array to the function?

Tags: java, arrays, class, instrumentation, redefine

I used `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation#redefineClasses()` to redefine existing classes. Sometimes, I need to redefine several classes.

If I redefine classes one by one, I will know which ones were successful and which ones failed.

But is it better to put classes redefined in an array together to get more correctness?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> If I redefine class one by one, I will know which is success, which is
>   failed.

True.

> But is it better to put classes redefined in an array together to get
>   more correctness?

I didn't get what you meant by more correctness! But, anyways from my understanding, using a set(array) of classes can be particularly helpful in the case where there is an interdependence of one class on other class. So, in this case you can re-define both classes by passing them in this method.

---

Also, [Java Documentation of Interface Instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses(java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...)) says :

> This method is used to replace the definition of a class without
>   reference to the existing class file bytes, as one might do when
>   recompiling from source for fix-and-continue debugging.
>
> ...
>
> ***This method operates on a set in order to allow interdependent changes to more than one class at the same time (a redefinition of
>   class A can require a redefinition of class B).***

But, do keep remember :

> If this method throws an exception, no classes have been redefined.

Answer (score 1):

It is much more performant to instrument classes in a batch compared to passing each class individually.

The JVM needs to halt the application for applying the redefinition which is a rather costly operation so it is worth grouping up.

Also, grouping allows for interdependent changes of classes.